# Oracle Apex - Using Multiple tabs with the same session state

Tags: session, tabs, session-cookies, oracle-apex

I am currently providing support to an existing Oracle Apex 4.2.5 application. One of the pages (Page 1003) contains a process that submits information from the Page 1003 page items (e.g. P1003_ITEM1) to our database tables. The contents of these page items are associated with a primary key (Assessment ID) in the database table to which the page items are submitted. Of a few dozen or so page item variables, the primary key is one of only three variables that are passed in through the URL. The URL is as follows:

```
    https://[DOMAIN]/f?p=[APPLICATION ID]:[PAGE NUMBER]:[SESSION ID]:SELECT:NO:1003:P1003_ENTITY_ID,P1003_ASSESSMENT_ID,P1003_PARENT_ID:353767,700177,5716
```

We have encountered an issue that occurs when our users load Page 1003 in multiple tabs in their browser for different Assessment#'s. Every time a new Page 1003 is loaded in a new tab, the session variables from the previous tab are overwritten. Regardless of which tab the user submits first, the only variables submitted to the database are the ones from the last tab that was loaded by the user. I've seen a few examples online of how to handle similar issues with other programming languages, but I'd like to know if there is an APEX specific solution that I might have overlooked that can handle this situation.

We'd prefer to pass as few variables as possible in to the page through the URL. In fact, some variable are calculated after the page loads and cannot be passed in through the URL.

Comment: First thought is to use AJAX... It is quite simple in APEX. For example, send ajax request to change current ID in session state, wait for response and then submit the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Dmitry! To make sure I understand correctly, when you say ID, are you referring to the session state ID or do you mean changing the name of each page item variable that is stored in the current session state?

Comment: As I understand, your page shows a row from a table, item `P1003_ITEM1` shows a primary key (which I named "ID") and you need to update other fields for row with this "ID". And if user opens several pages with different "ID"s, apex updates the last opened. So I proposed to update this "ID" (i. e. `P1003_ITEM1`) in session state.

Comment: Could you post a complete url from one assessment tab?

Comment: If a URL is used which contains an assesment id as an item's value, it doesn't make sense how opening multiple tabs with different ids would overwrite the value in other tabs. This may be dependent on the setup of the page and items though. But normally, the item is a PK field, and all values are fetched through a process. The ID is stored in an item on the page's html. When submitting the page, this ID is mapped back to the item value in session state and that record should be updated. As @Typo says: post one or more of your URLs here, then we can elaborate further.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I've added the URL in my edits above. I've also added some claification to the original post: The Primary Key is being passed in through the URL. Most of the other fields are derived from page items that are calculated after the page loads and are not passed in through the URL.

Comment: What's your page cache configuration?, you could try adding a clear cache process before loading the page

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no cache settings on the page besides the default ones. I've never really worked with caching before. From what I read about it just now online, it sounds like it would essentially take a snapshot of my page each time I load it. Would it be possible to trigger the process to clear the cache each time a user returns to a previous tab that they opened? If so, how would I retrieve the page items from only the current tab now that my cache is cleared?